# SELECT RECORD FROM TWO TABLE IN SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two table `AccountMaster` and `TransactionMaster`.

AccountMaster have column `Accounno` and TransactionMaster have `Accno, Amount` and `Transtype`.

AccountMaster have `5100` record. `TransactionMaster` have also `5100` in `Transtype=1` but only 1700 in `Transtype=2`.

How can I select all `5100` record in `Transtype=2` with `null value` which are note present in `TransactionMaster`.

Comment: Do not write everything UPPERCASE

Comment: provide sample data and its output

Answer (score 0):

You need to use left join on `ACCOUNTMASTER`

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ACCOUNTMASTER_TABLE AS AMT
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONMASTER AS TMT ON AMT.ACCOUNNO=TMT.ACCNO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick script which can be solved with the following:

```
select
*
from            AccountMaster       m
left outer join TransactionMaster   t   on  m.Accountno =   t.Accno
where           t.Accountno is null
```

Let me know if it works.